# unable to perform date validation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text box where i will be giving the date in text box and i need to compare that given date in text box with todays date it working for past date which is the expected result but if i am giving future date its still showing me the validation instead of inserting the date.How can i resolve this issue

Below is my code that i have used

```
var currentdate = new Date();

var todayDate = (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentdate.getDate() + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear();
if ($("#txtDate").val() < todayDate)  //txtdate is 10/20/2019 and today date is 09/20/2019 but still i am getting validation which should not happen
{
            MessageDisp('divAlertMessage', "Date Cannot Be Less Than Today's Date.", 'Error');
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I believe you have to convert `$("#txtDate").val()` into a data also.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing text and not date object and hence getting wrong result.
convert text value to date and then compare two dates for validation.

```js
$(function(){

var currentdate = new Date();
 $('#btnValidate').on('click', function(){
    var dateTxt = $('#txtDate').val();
    var date = new Date(dateTxt);
    
    if(date < currentdate) {
      console.log("Date Cannot Be Less Than Today's Date.");
      return false;
    }  else {
      console.log("Date is more Than Today's Date.");
      return true;
    }
 });

        
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='txtDate'><br>
<input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Validate">
```